# makeArray doesn't return the real array with jquery type

Tags: jquery

I've found the following code while reading `$.map()` jquery function

```
// The following object masquerades as an array. 
var fakeArray = {"length": 1, 0: "Addy", 1: "Subtracty"}; 
// Therefore, convert it to a real array 
var realArray = $.makeArray( fakeArray ) 
// Now it can be used reliably with $.map() 
$.map( realArray, function(val, i) { // do something });
```

But seems having problem with $.makeArray()

Let see the example below:

```
var fakeArr = {0,1,2};
var realArr = $.makeArray(fakeArr);
if($.type(realArr)==="array")
$('div').text(realArr.join());// doesn't return the array text
```

I also tried with `$.isArray()` which also doesn't results in array

But If I just do like this:

```
var realArr = [0,1,2];
if($.type(realArr)==="array")
$('div').text(realArr.join());// returns the array text
```

So, `$.makeArray` really returns the real Array?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: $.makeArray() should have converted {0,1,2} to [0,1,2].

Comment: @C-link We have a long conversion and you still want to convert `{0,1,2}`, how can we say?

Comment: @xdazz couldn't understand!

Comment: @C-link There is no such thing like `{0,1,2}` in javascript, agree?

Comment: @C-link - `{1,2,3}` isn't valid javascript so your question here just makes no sense.

Comment: @C-link You post a piece code don't even run and ask why, this should not be a 6K user's mistake.

Comment: so, the documentation is wrong seen in $.map() function?

Comment: @C-link Where did you see `{1,2,3}` in the documentation???

Comment: Seen here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Comment: @C-link I only see `{ "length": 2, 0: "Addy", 1: "Subtracty" }` which is an array-like object.

Comment: yeah, that's it but I've seen this on compile version of 1.8 jquery and the arry-like object is converted to array with $.makeArray(). I think I'm misunderstanding that?

Comment: @C-link First run your example and then ask.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fakeArr = {0,1,2};
```

This is just not valid in javascript.

See the description of `$.makeArray`, it is used to **Convert an array-like object into a true JavaScript array**. Something like `NodeList` is called array-like object.

---

Update:

If you mean why your first piece code converts `fakeArray` to `['Addy']` not `['Addy', 'Subtracty']`, that's because the `length` of your `fakeArray` is only `1`, which should be `2`.

**Array-like objects** — *those with a `.length` property and a value on the `.length - 1` index*

Comment: but with $.makeArr() is converted in array seen in $.map() function

Comment: @C-link Sorry, but what is your real problem?

Comment: so, $.makeArray is not converting that's it.

Comment: @C-link Converting what?? `{0,1,2}` ?

Comment: @C-link You mean your first piece of code? In your example, you want to convert `{0,1,2}` to an array, but `{0,1,2}` is not valid in js, so what's your point?

Comment: yes that's one. and with $.makeArr() is converted to array seen in $.map() what about that?

Comment: yeah with the $.map() it works but in another condition like in my question doesn't work why?

Answer (score 0):

I just seen your problem, what seems to me you want to make an array out of an object as provided by you on the top, if you go to [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) you can see that your **javascript object** is not valid so that might be the case.

try this instead:

```
var fakeArray = {"length": "1", "0": "Addy", "1": "Subtracty"};
// Therefore, convert it to a real array 
var realArray = $.makeArray(fakeArray);

console.log(realArray);
```

Here your object keys and values have been quoted with `""` double quotes.

Tested here: [**Demo @ Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GXC8n/)

Comment: It's not about json, it's just javascript.

Comment: @xdazz i agree but to make sure it's validity i just tried something on jsonlint and that shows it is invalid.

Comment: It's totally valid in javascript.

Comment: just need to get more info about it, this is not working `var fakeArray = {};
fakeArray.length = 1;
fakeArray.0 = "Addy";
fakeArray.1 = "Subtracty";` when i `console.log(fakeArray);`  But this works `var fakeArray = {};
fakeArray.length = 1;
fakeArray.a = "Addy";
fakeArray.b = "Subtracty";`

Comment: It should be `fakeArray[1] = "Subtracty"`.

Comment: @xdazz thanks for this i got somthing out of it, **yes you are correct**.